# Generic matrix type in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, c++14, template-meta-programming

This snippet is about a generic matrix type. The nice part is that given two matrices with respective entry types, say, of **`short`** and **`float`**, the result matrix entry type after the multiplication will be **`float`**.

**matrix.h**:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class matrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> content;
    size_t width;
    size_t height;

public:
    matrix(size_t width_, size_t height_) : width{width_}, height{height_}
    {
        content.resize(height);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        {
            content[i].resize(width);
        }
    }

    const std::vector<T>& operator[](size_t row_index) const {
        return content[row_index];
    }

    std::vector<T>& operator[](size_t row_index) {
        return content[row_index];
    }

    size_t get_width()  const { return width; }
    size_t get_height() const { return height; }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(const matrix<T1>& a, const matrix<T2>& b) -> matrix<decltype(T1{} * T2{})>
{
    if (a.get_height() != b.get_width())
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Matrix dimenstion mismatch: ";
        ss << a.get_height();
        ss << " x ";
        ss << a.get_width();
        ss << " times ";
        ss << b.get_height();
        ss << " x ";
        ss << b.get_width();
        ss << ".";
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

    using value_type = decltype(T1{} + T2{});
    matrix<decltype(T1{} * T2{})> result(a.get_height(), b.get_width());

    for (size_t rowa = 0; rowa != a.get_height(); ++rowa)
    {
        for (size_t colb = 0; colb != b.get_width(); ++colb)
        {
            value_type sum = 0;

            for (size_t i = 0; i != a.get_width(); ++i)
            {
                sum += a[rowa][i] * b[i][colb];
            }

            result[rowa][colb] = sum;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, matrix<T> m)
{
    size_t maximum_entry_length = 0;

    for (size_t row = 0; row < m.get_height(); ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < m.get_width(); ++col)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << m[row][col];
            std::string entry_text;
            ss >> entry_text;
            maximum_entry_length = std::max(maximum_entry_length,
                                            entry_text.length());
        }
    }

    for (size_t row = 0; row < m.get_height(); ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < m.get_width(); ++col)
        {
            os << std::setw((int) maximum_entry_length) << m[row][col];

            if (col < m.get_width() - 1)
            {
                os << ' ';
            }
        }

        if (row < m.get_height() - 1)
        {
            os << '\n';
        }
    }

    return os;
}

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    matrix<int> A(3, 2);

    A[0][0] = 1;
    A[0][1] = 2;
    A[0][2] = 3;
    A[1][0] = 4;
    A[1][1] = 5;
    A[1][2] = 6;

    cout << "A: " << endl;
    cout << A << endl << endl;

    matrix<float> B(2, 3);

    B[0][0] = 5.0f;
    B[0][1] = 4.0f;
    B[1][0] = 3.0f;
    B[1][1] = 2.0f;
    B[2][0] = 1.0f;
    B[2][1] = 0.0f;

    cout << "B: " << endl;
    cout << B << endl << endl;

    auto result = A * B;
    cout << "AB:" << endl;
    cout << result << endl << endl;

    result = B * A;
    cout << "BA:" << endl;
    cout << result << endl;

    matrix<short> F(4, 4);
    try
    {
        F * A;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& err)
    {
        cerr << err.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: @user2296177 Sure. But how would I implement the double subscript operator?

Comment: @user2296177 Why not make an answer with the two points?

Comment: I've just posted very similar code as [an answer to a different question](/a/142821) - I made the dimensions part of the type, and use modern `decltype()` and Concepts, but you may find it interesting anyway.

Comment: My opinion is to have dimensions as part of the type. On top of that, `operator()(std::size_t` will need to return `std::array<>` in order to avoid users trying to resize it. Additionally, multiplication will issue compile time error if used with wrong dimensions. I think just storing raw pointer to `std::array<std::array<>>` is ok.

Comment: @Olzhas My implicit requirement for the matrix type is that its dimensions are known only at runtime. Therefore vector of vectors.

Comment: @TobySpeight Can you answer my question with emphasis on move semantics in matrix **`operator*`**? That would be awesome.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer but your matrix multiplication is slow for large matrices. There are more efficient methods with lower memory bandwidth, see Wikipedia for example:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm in general I advise against building your own math primitives for anything else than a learning experience. It's not worth the time and you will likely end up with something suboptimal any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Use one vector instead of two vectors

You can improve performance by using one vector instead of two vectors; you can calculate the 2nd dimension using a little math. This is actually how primitive 2D arrays work in C++.

Advantages:

- Elements stay in contiguous storage, as opposed to linked-list-like structure where every row leads to an entirely different memory (in terms of adjacency). This is beneficial for the cache.
- Easy to implement

Disadvantages:

- You can no longer use the idiomatic `matrix[i][j]` syntax, thus you must provide your own access operator.

Possible implementation (please read the comments, they contain additional review items):

```
#include <cstddef> // added missing header for std::size_t
#include <vector>

// this macro can be replaced by a private (nearly guaranteed to be inlined) function
#define matrix_index(i, j) i * columns + j

template<class T>
class matrix
{
public:
    // use type aliases so that users can correctly refer to values
    using value_type = typename std::vector<T>::value_type;
    using reference = typename std::vector<T>::reference;
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;

    matrix(size_type const r, size_type const c)
        : rows{ r }
        , columns{ c }
    {
        // rows * colums = total memory
        data.resize(r * c);
    }

    reference operator()(size_type const i, size_type const j) noexcept
    {
        return data[matrix_index(i, j)];
    }

    /* ... */        

    // you can make these public and const, they never change
    size_type const rows;
    size_type const columns;

private:
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

Sample usage:

```
for (matrix<int>::size_type i{ 0 }; i != m.rows; ++i)
{
    for (matrix<int>::size_type j{ 0 }; j != m.columns; ++j)
    {
        m(i, j) = i * j;
    }
}
```

#### Provide a constructor that directly initializes the matrix

Currently, you have to call `resize()`, which simply allocates and default constructs the number of specified elements. This is inefficient unless you want a default-initialized matrix.

Provide a constructor that allows you initialize the matrix directly:

```
matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<value_type>> row_list)
    : rows{ row_list.size() }
    , columns{ row_list.begin()->size() }
{
    data.reserve(rows * columns);
    for (auto const& row : row_list)
    {
        data.insert(data.cend(), row);
    }
}
```

This means that you can now construct matrices directly like so:

```
matrix<int> m
{
    { 1, 2, 3 }, // row 1
    { 4, 5, 6 }  // row 2
};
```

Please note that this is a trivial implementation.

You should verify that the internal `std::initializer_list<>` instances all have the same size (or fill in the missing values with a default value such as 0). You can turn this into a "no-overhead" check by simply using `assert()` and having the `NDEBUG` macro defined in release mode.